# Unable recognize an object on a Silverlight app using Ranorex automation

Tags: automation, ranorex

I am not able to recognize an object on a Silverlight app using Ranorex automation.  Whole app is identified as a single window. Objects like dropdown, buttons etc inside an silverlight app is not recognized with ranorex tool. With this I am not able to continue my automation. Please provide the solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was already answered in the following thread in the Ranorex Forum.http://www.ranorex.com/forum/not-able-to-detect-ui-objects-inside-a-silverlight-applicatn-t4335.html

Comment: Can you edit your answer and post the relevant part of the solution here?